# prepareForSegue giving Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, swift

I have two controllers named `RootViewController` and `CountrySelectionActivityViewController`. I have written a prepareForSegue function to pass data from first to the second view. I have a navigation controller in which the view is embedded in. So, here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "next") {
        let mynavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let vc = mynavigationController.topViewController as CountrySelectionActivityViewController
        vc.countries = countries
    }
}
```

If I comment out this code, my app runs and moves to the next viewcontroller. Though, the data is not passed if this function is not implemented. What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Which line is the problem on? Is the segue identifier definitely set in Interface Builder? (Also: had you previously set up this segue in an earlier beta? I found I had problems until I went into IB and re-typed-in my existing segue identifiers in beta 7...)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same objetive as you, passing variables between controllers when performing a segue.

My solution was to create two variables in each controller and related them through a custom segue.

In order to define the custom segue a new class is creaded: CustomPushSegue.m. This file has the implementation of `-(void)perfom`. This class is of type `UIStoryboardSegue` and has origin and destination variables of type `UIViewController`.

Then the idea is to cast each viewController of destination and origin as the custom controllers and pass the variables:

```
#import "OriginController.h"
#import "DestinationController.h"

-(void) perform {
    UIViewController *destinationController = self.setinationViewController;
    UIViewController *originController = self.sourceViewController;

    if ([[self identifier] isEqualToString : @"Segue"]){
        (DestinationController*) destinationController.var1 = (OriginController*) originController.var1;
    }

    //Stuff related to the performance of the Segue goes here
}
```

If you require further information, please ask. I can send you some sample files.